# How to scrape data off morningstar

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So Im new to the world of web scraping and so far I've only really been using beautifulsoup to scrape text and images off websites. I thought Id try and scrape some data points off a graph to test my understanding but I got a bit confused at this [graph](https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR050AQ&tab=13).

After inspecting the element of the piece of data I wanted to extract, I saw this:
`<span id="TSMAIN">: 100.7490637</span>`
The problem is, my original idea for scraping the data points would be to have iterated through some sort of id list containing all the different data points (if that makes sense?).

Instead, it seems that all the data points are contained within this same element, and the value depends on where your cursor is on the graph.

My problem is, If I use beautifulsoups find function and type in that specific element with that attribute of `id` = `TSMAIN`, I get a none type return, because I am guessing unless I have my cursor on the actual graph nothing will show up there.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}
url = "https://www.morningstar.co.uk/uk/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR050AQ&tab=13"
source=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content,'lxml')
data = soup.find("span",attrs={"id":"TSMAIN"})
print(data)
```

Output

```
None
```

How can I extract all the data points of this graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the data can be pulled form API. Only thing is the values it returns is relative to the start date entered in the payload. It'll set the out put of the start date to `0`, then the numbers after are relative to that date.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

userInput = input('Choose:\n\t1. 3 Month\n\t2. 6 Month\n\t3. 1 Year\n\t4. 3 Year\n\t5. 5 Year\n\t6. 10 Year\n\n -->: ')
userDict = {'1':3,'2':6,'3':12,'4':36,'5':60,'6':120}


n = datetime.now()
n = n - relativedelta.relativedelta(days=1)
n = n - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=userDict[userInput])
dateStr = n.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


url = 'https://tools.morningstar.co.uk/api/rest.svc/timeseries_cumulativereturn/t92wz0sj7c'

data = []
idDict = {
        'Schroder Managed Balanced Instl Acc':'F0GBR050AQ]2]0]FOGBR$$ALL',
        'GBP Moderately Adventurous Allocation':'EUCA000916]8]0]CAALL$$ALL',
        'Mixed Investment 40-85% Shares':'LC00000012]8]0]CAALL$$ALL',
        '':'F00000ZOR1]7]0]IXALL$$ALL',}


for k, v in idDict.items():
    payload = {
    'encyId': 'GBP',
    'idtype': 'Morningstar',
    'frequency': 'daily',
    'startDate':  dateStr,
    'performanceType': '',
    'outputType': 'COMPACTJSON',
    'id': v,
    'decPlaces': '8',
    'applyTrackRecordExtension': 'false'}
    
    
    temp_data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(temp_data)
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df[0], unit='ms')
    df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date 
    df = df[['date',1]]  
    df.columns = ['date', k]
    data.append(df)         

final_df = pd.concat(
    (iDF.set_index('date') for iDF in data),
    axis=1, join='inner'
).reset_index()


final_df.plot(x="date", y=list(idDict.keys()), kind="line")
```

**Output:**

```
print (final_df.head(5).to_string())
         date  Schroder Managed Balanced Instl Acc  GBP Moderately Adventurous Allocation  Mixed Investment 40-85% Shares          
0  2019-12-22                             0.000000                               0.000000                        0.000000  0.000000
1  2019-12-23                             0.357143                               0.406784                        0.431372  0.694508
2  2019-12-24                             0.714286                               0.616217                        0.632422  0.667586
3  2019-12-25                             0.714286                               0.616217                        0.632422  0.655917
4  2019-12-26                             0.714286                               0.612474                        0.629152  0.664124
....
```

To get those Ids, it took a little investigating of the requests. Searching through those, I was able to find the corresponding id values and with a little bit of trial and error to work out what values meant what.

[image]

Those "alternate" ids used. And where those line graphs get the data from (inthose 4 request, look at the Preview pane, and you'll see the data in there.

[image]

Here's the final output/graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but does that mean its impossible to use webscraping to get these sorts of data? I wouldve thought maybe the answer was another package like scrapy or maybe selenium? Ive heard these names before when it comes to webscraping. Just want to check what to do in the case where APIs dont exist as a solution

Comment: For dynamic sites where the data is rendered by javascript, you're correct, using a simple request won't work. Selenium could certainly work here, and for those sites with no api, as it allows the html to be rendered before pulling the html source. APIs though are nice in that it's structure is consistent and you usually get even more data that what you see on the site. Also SOMETIMES, you will see the data in json format in the `<script>` tags. It's just a matter of pulling those out and manipulation the string to a valid json format.

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for this api? I cant seem to find it anywhere on the web. I would like to scrape some other graphs off morning star.

Comment: couldn't find the documentation either. Simply had to look at the dev tools to sort of see what values/parameters to use as I click around the site.

Comment: Do you have a link to what page you saw? Im not sure how you discovered the arguements:
        'Schroder Managed Balanced Instl Acc':'F0GBR050AQ]2]0]FOGBR$$ALL',
        'GBP Moderately Adventurous Allocation':'EUCA000916]8]0]CAALL$$ALL',
        'Mixed Investment 40-85% Shares':'LC00000012]8]0]CAALL$$ALL',
        '':'F00000ZOR1]7]0]IXALL$$ALL',}
I get the keys are just the names of the lines but where did you find these values?

Comment: I added a little more info in the solutions. It's not as straightforward. I had to do a little bit of trial and error to find it, but those values do come back in a separate response.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I managed to find the IDs as youve mentioned in your answer but the issue is this. Youve got the ID for, lets say, GBP Moderately Adventurous Allocation as EUCA000916]8]0]CAALL$$ALL. Inspecting the HTML I can only find EUCA00091680 under ID, where did you discover the CAALL$$ALL part at the end? Sorry for the extended discussion but it would help me out a lot to be able to re use this.

Comment: Ahhh. i see what you mean. Again ya, just sort of had to search around for it (I'll add another photo...there 4 requests made that had that in there). Like I said I said before, this took me a lot of trial and error and just playing around. This site isn't exactly a straightforward one to scrape, none-the-less still good way to learn how to do all this.

Comment: @chitown88 Really love this. Could you ELI5 a little bit more? I'm a scraping n00b as well.

Comment: @chitown88 Specifically
1. How did you get the url? The url you used is different from the one in the question.
2. In the id-dict, how did you know which of the values corresponded to each line?
3. How did you know the 4 "t92wz0sj..." requests corresponded to each of the 4 line graphs (other than there are 4 of them?)
4. How did you know to look the at "XHR" tab? What do the other Network tabs mean?

Comment: @chitown88 How would you go about scraping this table? https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/goog/performance

Comment: @Alexander I’ll take a look tomorrow

Comment: @Alexander actually, email me (with the questions too). Might be easier to take this conversation away from the comments. Jason.schvach@gmail.com